# Dimension of quintic hypersurfaces singular at given number of points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, hypersurfaces

How many quintic hypersurfaces are there which are singular at given points (need not be general) of length at least 20? Is there any upper bound of the dimension of such quintics?

Comment: Hypersurfaces in what?

Comment: hypersurfaces of degree $5$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Comment: The quintics singular at three collinear points are singular along the line so if all 23 points are collinear then only the first 3 impose conditions. That is probably the sharp bound for the fewest conditions imposed by 23 singularities (double points) but I would have to think about the proof.

Comment: Hm, might need singularity at 5 collinear points to get singularity along the line. (So every first derivative vanishes at 5 points.) Sorry, but I’m not very confident about the specific numbers. Still, I have a hunch/guess that collinear double points impose the fewest conditions.